# Magento2 backend Reorder issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, admin-controller, reorder

I need to display the Order custom attribute values in magento2 admin re-order page. 
I tried the code like

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
        $session = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
```

but didn't get any value. Can you please anyone help me.
[image]